# Infinite set of standard primes as the set of standard prime divisors of a nonstandard number

Tags: logic, model-theory, peano-axioms, nonstandard-models

Suppose $(N, +, \cdot, 0, 1, <, =)$ is a proper elementary substructure of $(N^*, +^*, \cdot^*, 0^*, 1^*, =^*, <^*)$. Show that there exists some (infinite) $b$, where $b ∈ N^*$, such that for each prime number $p ∈ N$, $N^* \models p | b$ iff $p ∈ S$, where $S$ is some set containing infinitely many primes.

Comment: Do you mean "for _every_ $S$ and every prime $p\in\mathbb N$, the equivalence holds" or do you mean "there exists _some_ $S$ such that for every prime $p\in\mathbb N$, the equivalence holds"? The former statement is not (always) true, but the latter is.

Comment: I think it is for some S.

Comment: The quantifier on $S$ is still not very clear. Is $S$ is given in advance, or are you free to choose it so long as it is infinite?

Comment: You're free to choose S so long as its infinite.

Comment: @Arthur: Do we need a new tags for non-standard models?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I'm writing up a meta question on this presently.  Stay tuned.

Answer (score 3):

If we choose $S$ to be the collection of all the standard primes, then it suffices to set $b=H!$ for some infinite integer $H$. Since the standard model satisfies the elementary formula expressing the factorial, the same formula evaluated at $H$ will give a non-standard integer divisible by all the primes up to $H$ by elementary equivalence, and in particular by all the finite primes in $S$.